# How to add a click event handler to Ext JS picker child element?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to be able to add a link into the combo box drop down list that does something.

I did this by changing the template. However adding a click event listener doesn't work, does anyone know why?

```js
items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Combo with extra option',
                store: {
                    fields: ['value', 'display'],
                    data: [
                        { value: 1, display: 'First' },
                        { value: 2, display: 'Second' }
                    ]
                },
                valueField: 'value',
                displayField: 'display',
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<div style="background-color: lightblue;" class="searchItem">Search</div>',
                        '<ul class="x-list-plain">',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                            '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{display} - {value}</li>',
                        '</tpl></ul>'
                ),
                listeners: {
                boxready: function(field) {
                    var picker = field.getPicker();
                    picker.on('boxready', function() {
                        var searchItem = Ext.get(this.getEl().query('.searchItem')[0]);
                        searchItem.on('click', function() { alert('test'); });//this doesn't do anything
                    })
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a listener configuration to your [`listConfig`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-listConfig) instead of the combobox. That way you access the actual list instead of the entire combobox.

Secondly, have a look at the general [configuration for an event listener](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/classic/Ext.html#method-on). You need to make use of the options `element` and `delegate`.

The `element` option requires an Ext.dom.Element to add a listener to. In your case, you can use `el` as value to add the entire element.

The `delegate` option requires a selector like `div.searchItem`. Putting this all together would create the following `listConfig`:

```
            listConfig: {
                listeners: {
                    click: {
                        element: 'el',
                        delegate: 'div.searchItem',
                        fn: function (event, target) {
                            alert('test');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```